# can't pass multiple parameters using mvc4 html.beginform(...)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.beginform

In my mvc4 application i want to use html.beginform() to pass multiple parameters to an actionResult on the same controller.

I do it like this:

view:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddNote", "Lead",FormMethod.Post, null))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("leadID",@Model.ID)
        <input type="text" name="noteBody" />
        <input type="submit" class="mainButton" value="Add New!"/>
    }
</div>
```

Controller (LeadController):

```
[HttpPost]
ActionResult AddNote(int leadID, string noteBody)
{
    Note note = new Note();
    note.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
    note.Title = "No Title";
    note.Body = noteBody;

    Lead lead = unitOfWork.LeadRepository.GetById(leadID);
    lead.Notes.Add(note);

    unitOfWork.Save();

    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = leadID });
}
```

when i press the submit button i get an exception:

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Lead/AddNote

this is the place to say that i have tried it withput parameters and it worked just fine.
I've also tried to pass the "leadID" parameter inside the form declaration (new {leadID = @Model.ID}).

Any idea what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have the `[HttpPost]` attribute on your `AddNote` action? Are you using some custom routes?

Comment: I do have the [HttpPost] on my action. seems like this is not the root cause. what do you mean by custom routs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the 'public' modifier to your action and it will do the magic.

Answer (score 1):

The `AddNote` method should be `public`. Use the `public` keyword and it will work.

Comment: Please expand on what you mean here; why does making it public work?

Comment: Controller is a class like other classes... you can't access private methods, properties, fields,... from outside. Just make it public, and it should work (if you didn't mess with routing, like mentioned). BTW, if you hover your mouse pointer over the AddNote string in the view (where the @using (Html.BeginForm("AddNote",... is), does it say: "Cannot resolve action 'AddNote'?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `HTTPPOST` attribute , like this

```
[HttpPost]
ActionResult AddNote(int leadID, string noteBody)
{
    Note note = new Note();
    note.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
    note.Title = "No Title";
    note.Body = noteBody;

    Lead lead = unitOfWork.LeadRepository.GetById(leadID);
    lead.Notes.Add(note);

    unitOfWork.Save();

    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = leadID });
}
```

Perhaps it helps you